# Javascript function to show a hidden button with setTimeout not working in a PDF

Tags: javascript, pdf

I have an interactive PDF with a form field button called “Nav_Forward_Page_14” that is set to hidden. I want the button to be visible 10 seconds after the page containing the button loads; so on Page Properties (for the page with the button), I've tried adding the following Javascript on page load, but neither script is working:

```
setTimeout(function() {
this.getElementById("Nav_Forward_Page_14").style.display = "inline"; 
}, 10000);
```

Thinking that I may have the function wrong, I also tried:

```
setTimeout(function() {
this.getElementById("Nav_Forward_Page_14").display = display.visible; 
}, 10000);
```

Please help me correct the function necessary to show the hidden button after a delay on page load in a PDF.  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document.body.onload = function(){}` which will execute once the DOM body is loaded which is the same as putting your script on the bottom of your `<body>` tag.

I made the delay `3 seconds` to not waste time, you can edit yourself.

Here is a more simplified example:

---

```js
var delay = 3000;

document.body.onload = function() {
 setTimeout(() => {
   document.querySelector('button').style.display = 'inline';
  }, delay);
}
```

```css
button {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button>Next page</button>
```

Comment: Thank you Alex. I have tried your suggestion, something still isn't working in the PDF.  Since my button is already defined as a form field button on the page and set to hidden, can I sub 'button' in the document.body.onload function for 'Nav_Forward_Page_14'?

Answer (score 0):

Got this to work in the PDF when added as Javascript to page open:

```
function runImage() {
this.getField("Nav_Forward_Page_14").display = display.visible
}
run = app.setTimeOut("runImage()", 10000);
```